# How To Read Arabic charset data in Asp.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle, character-encoding

I am using this code to read data from Oracle Database. That data stored in Oracle is Navarchar2 data type but when It it display in gridview it looks like this. ?& ? ?????? ??? ? My database Charaacter set is WE8MSWIN1252

Here is mY code through which I am reading from Oracle database.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      Dim con = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=cms; User ID=cms20112012; Password=??????; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")           
       con.open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select to_char(grower_Name) grower from V_GROW", con)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim I As Long
        da.Fill(ds, "V_GROW")
        GridView1.DataSource = ds
        GridView1.DataBind()
        For I = 0 To ds.Tables("V_GROW").Rows.Count - 1
            Dim grower As String = ds.Tables("V_GROW").Rows(I).Item("grower")
            grower = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(grower))
            Label1.Text = grower
        Next I
        con.close()
    End Sub
```

Please anyone help me to get out of this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database needs to use the UTF encoding or it will not store / retrieve correctly.  When you setup the Oracle database - you must set the character set (National and Database) to UTF.

Answer (score 0):

What is the national character set of the database?  What data type is `GROWER_NAME`?

Assuming that `GROWER_NAME` is an `NVARCHAR2` and that the national character set is AL16UTF16

1. You don't want to call `TO_CHAR` in your query.
2. You don't want to convert the data from Unicode to ASCII before displaying it.  ASCII cannot encode Arabic data so the data will invariably get corrupted.

Are you certain that the Arabic data has been written to the database correctly?  What does

```
SELECT dump(grower_name, 1016)
  FROM v_grow
 WHERE rownum < 2
```

return (assuming every row has Arabic data).

Comment: Yes I am storing Data In Nvarchar2 data type and my Database NLS_CHARACTERSET is WE8MSWIN1252 and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET is AL16UTF16 and through your method my data has changed into this form   Typ=1 Len=30 CharacterSet=AL16UTF16: 0,d8,0,a7,0,d9,20,1e,0,d9,20,1e,0,db,0,81,0,20,0,d8,0,a8,0,d8,0,ae,0,d8,0,b4

Comment: Sir R u there Please Help me Here

Comment: @user1220667 - What Arabic data is that `DUMP` output supposed to represent?  That data does not appear to be validly encoded UTF-16 Arabic data.  How is the data being inserted into Oracle?

Comment: Data is Inserting into Database through a PHP web form

Comment: @user1220667 - It doesn't appear that the PHP app is writing the Arabic data correctly.  That's definitely going to make it much harder for your app to read it correctly.

Comment: So What Should I do Now at this Stage .

Comment: @user1220667 - It appears that you need to debug the 
PHP application so that it writes the Arabic data correctly.

Comment: I have a aspx form in which same data is being read in treeview in exact arabic format.But this form is developed by anyother developer and is in compiled form.so that i cant view how data is reading.But I show u the page where is the data is being read.Here is the link  http://sml.com.pk/a/cms/gis.php

Comment: @user1220667 - The data is not being saved in the UTF-16 format.  If you can tell us what character set the data is actually encoded in, it's possible to write an application that will display the data.  But it would require that you configure your environment incorrectly, lie to Oracle about the character set of the data coming in and going out, and manipulate the character set internally.  That, in turn, forces every other application that wants to use this data to do the same thing.  In the long term, you're better fixing the encoding problem now.